# like TestNG @dataprovider is used for provide multiple data to the test case...like that any methods or package is used in playwright?

Tags: excel, input, playwright, dataprovider, ddt

In playwright is their any methods used for handle dataprovider concept or how to create own data provider for handle multiple inputs from multiple sheets.can anyone give some example here.  Thanks in Advance.